# Does std::bind discard type information of parameters in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, polymorphism, stdbind

**Case where the problem occours**

Please consider the following c++ code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Superclass
class A {
    public:
    virtual std::string get() const {
        return "A";
    }
};

// Subclass
class B : public A {
    public:
    virtual std::string get() const {
        return "B";
    }
};

// Simple function that prints the object type
void print(const A &instance) {
    std::cout << "It's " << instance.get() << std::endl;
}

// Class that holds a reference to an instance of A
class State {
    A &instance;
    public:
    State(A &instance) : instance(instance) { }
    void run() {

        // Invokes print on the instance directly
        print(instance);

        // Creates a new function by binding the instance
        // to the first parameter of the print function, 
        // then calls the function. 
        auto func = std::bind(&print, instance);    
        func();
    }    
};

int main() {
    B instance;
    State state(instance);

    state.run();
}
```

In this example, we have two classes `A` and `B`. `B` inherits from class `A`. Both classes implement a simple virtual method that returns the type name.

There is also a simple method, `print`, that accepts a reference to an instance of `A` and prints the type.

The class `State` holds a reference to an instance of `A`. The class also has a simple method that calls `print` by two different means.

**Where it gets odd**

The sole method in state first calls `print` directly. Since we supply an instance of `B` int the main method, the output is `It's B`, as expected.

For the second call, however, we bind the instance to the first parameter of `print` using `std::bind`. Then we call the resulting function without any arguments.

In this case, however, the output is `It's A`. I would have expected the output `It's B`, as before, since it is still the same instance.

If I declare the parameters as pointers instead of references, `std::bind` works as expected. I also placed some logging into the constructors of both classes to verify that no instances are created accidentally.

Why does this happen? Does `std::bind` discard some type information in this case? To my understanding, this must not happen since the method invocation should be managed by a vtable lookup via runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626). Pass the instance by reference:

```
auto func = std::bind(&print, std::ref(instance));
//                            ^^^^^^^^
```

To explain this a bit more: Like most C++ standard library types, the result type of a `bind` expression *owns* all its bound state. This means you can take this value and pass it around freely and store it and come back to it later in a different context, and you can still call it with all its bound state ready for action.

Therefore, in your code, the bind object was constructed with a *copy* of `instance`. But since `instance` wasn't a complete object, you caused slicing to happen.

By contrast, my code copies a `std::reference_wrapper<A>` into the bind object, and that's essentially a pointer. It doesn't own the instance object, so I need to keep it alive as long as the bind object may get called, but it means that the bound call is dispatched polymorphically to the complete object.

Comment: Why is it not already passed as reference? The variable given to std::bind is a reference, the argument for print is a reference too. To additional/temporaty instances are constructed.

Comment: @Emiswelt: The magic question is "what is *it*". *Something* is passed by reference, no doubt, but not what you think. In your case, the bind object itself holds a *sliced copy* of your instance (which it duly passes on by reference), whereas in my code it holds a reference wrapper.

Comment: @Emiswelt `std::bind` will pass its parameter either by copy or by move. Exception is `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Note that `bind` actually has special handling for `reference_wrapper`s - it always unwraps them.

Comment: @T.C.: You mean via *INVOKE*?

Comment: @KerrekSB No, before it gets to INVOKE. See first bullet in [func.bind.bind]/10.

Comment: @T.C.: Ah yes, the `get()` is built into `bind` -- you don't rely on the conversion function.

Comment: @T.C.: By the way, will you update the cppreference page on `std::invoke`?